# Core data select objects from an array - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, core-data

I was wondering if I could select objects based on a predicate with an array... for example

Code:
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id=%@", arrayOfID];

Will it work? If no, how can I do it?

Best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct predicate would be

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id IN %@", arrayOfID];
```

Assuming that arrayOfId contains objects of the same type as id (e.g. NSNumbers or NSStrings).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can do it.

Sounds like you need a bit of grounding in Core Data. I found the following tutorial really useful in getting me off the ground with Core Data:

http://iphoneinaction.manning.com/iphone_in_action/2009/08/core-data-part-1-an-introduction.html

Comment: You're right... I wasn't able to find a good tuto for the queries!

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... I get an error:
*** -[NSCFArray longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7e2d820
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7e2d820'


To be clear... id is an int and my array is an array of int!

Comment: It's not clear from what you've posted what the problem is. If the problem is suffieciently different from the current question, perhaps you could ask a new question?

Comment: The error seems to indicate that id is an NSNumber and that hence it tries to send longLongValue to an array because of the `id=%@` predicate. Replacing the = with IN should solve this error because it will send that message to the NSNumbers contained in the array.